# How to change the UILabel in a UITableViewCell that has been tapped

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've added 7 labels in one UITableViewCell, added a UITapGestureRecognizer and I've set the tap target-action.

I want that all labels can be tapped and change the tapped label to another backgroundColor.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //here I leave out how cell are added to the UITableView.

    self.repeatAll = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"MON", @"TUE",@"WED",@"THU",@"FRI",@"SAT",@"SUN", nil];
    int x =60;
    UILabel *label;
    for (int i =0; i<7; i++) {
        NSString *theText = [self.repeatAll objectAtIndex:i];
        label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.text = theText;
        label.frame = CGRectMake(x+label.frame.size.width, 30.0f, 30.0f, 20.0f);
        x = label.frame.size.width + 5+ x;
        label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(_tapLabel:)];
        [label addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
        [cell addSubview:label];        
    }
}

- (void)_tapLabel:(id)sender {
    //something I don't know how to change the target label. change it's backgroundColor
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
_tapLabel:(id)sender
```

to:

```
_tapLabel:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
```

and then get the tapped view via:

```
gesture.view
```

updating the color would be:

```
gesture.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```